# AngularFireModule Injection

Tags: angular, firebase, dependency-injection, angularfire

I need to get the config_object for AngularFire.initialize (config_object>) before my angular app run.

I tried with injection, but I'm not very familiar with that concept and don't understand how to use it.

If I do it sync like below it works like a charm, but I need to retrieve the config with an API call (with Axios).

And when I try to return an Axios promise, it doesn't work.

```js
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS,
      useFactory:  () => {
        return {
          apiKey: 'xxx',
          authDomain: 'xxx',
          projectId: 'xxx',
          storageBucket: 'xxx',
          messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
          appId: 'xxxx',
          measurementId: 'xxxxx',
        };
      },
    },
  ],
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: This remains a bit of an issue with Angular. What you basically are asking for are Async Providers. There are some discussions about these on the Angular repo. In general, there is a work-around for this which involves using fetch inside main.ts to get your config and then to provide it as a token during boot. I've found an example specifically for Firebase but have not tested this myself: https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/34857420.html

Comment: thanks @MikeOne with your example it totally worked !